# Wait for data collection from storageArea

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am struggling with a problem when gathering data from storage. I have onMessage event listener in background script waiting for a specific event. If this event is received - I need to collect some data from storageArea and then send it to content script. My problem is that I need to wait for this data to be collected(successfully or not) and only then proceed and send the data. If I try to send it from storageArea callback - my content script does not receive anything. If I just continue -> the script continues and does not wait for the data to be collected and again my content script does not receive anything. Bellow is the pseudo code to illustrate my problem:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
     //get the data from the storageArea
 var storageData = {};
 browser.storage.local.get("myData", function (data) {
         //modify storageData here 
 });
  //send response ONLY when the data is finished loading(successfully or not)
  sendResponse(storageData);
});
```

So my question is : how can I wait for the data to be collected and only then proceed? Maybe I shouldn't event wait and I should create some sort of " event chains"
or callbacks? I am not sure how to organize this yet. 
Thank you very much for you help guys!

Comment: Note, you can access browser.storage in the content script too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`browser.storage.local.get()` returns a `Promise` while `chrome.storage.local.get()` return a callback function.

You can choose whichever way you prefer.

**Promise then()**

```js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
     
  //get the data from the storageArea
  browser.storage.local.get('myData')
  .then (storageData => {
    // do wathever with storageData
    sendResponse(storageData);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error)); // in case of error
});
```

**async/await**

```js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender, sendResponse) => {

  //get the data from the storageArea
  const storageData = await browser.storage.local.get('myData');
  // do wathever with storageData
  sendResponse(storageData);
});
```

**callback function**

```js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
     
  //get the data from the storageArea
  chrome.storage.local.get('myData', storageData => {
    // do wathever with storageData
    sendResponse(storageData);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, @erosman. I've solved the issue using async/await, however, I cant receive the data in the content script - it is undefined. In the content script, I do the following:
browser.runtime.sendMessage({request: "type", data: "some_data"}).then(handleResponse, handleError). And when I receive the data in the handleResponse function it says that it is undefined. What should I change in my content script to receive the proper data from background script response?

Comment: I've solved the issue with data using your last option -> callback function. However, can you please explain why do you use "arrow" function instead of "normal" callback?

Comment: One more comment: I also added "return true" at the end of onMessage() event listener in the background script, because it finishes before the data is collected, but I need to send response anyway.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage
check "Sending an asynchronous response using sendResponse"

Comment: @MrMan arrow function is just easier to write. You can choose the normal function. Without seeing the code, it is difficult to say but a common oversight is sending the request too early to content script. Content scripts are injected by default at `document_idle` and if a message is sent before that, there is nothing in content to answer it. Above examples are just examples to show the possibilities and they have to be adapted to the actual situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @erosman. There are no problems with content script loading, because content script initiates the communication with background script when the page is loaded(run_at is set to "document_idle" in the manifest file)

Answer (score -1):

you can you the below exemple

```
browser.storage.local.get(function(storageData){
    // modify storage data 
    // ... 

    sendResponse(storageData);
});
```